# How to copy SSH from JENKINS host into a DOCKER container?

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh

I can't copy the file from the host into the container using the Dockerfile, because i'm simply [not allowed to](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy), as mentioned in Docker Documentation:

> The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot
>   COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build
>   is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker
>   daemon.

---

I'm also unable to do so from inside jenkins job, because the job commands run inside the shell of the docker container, there is not way to talk to the parent(which is the jenkins host).

---

[This jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) could have been a life saver, but as mentioned in the first section: distribution of this plugin has been suspended due to unresolved security vulnerabilities.

Comment: do you have any VOLUME that you can use? copy to this path in the host server, and then run another command in the container to copy from this VOLUME... i didn't try but can work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I copy files from host to docker image using Dockerfile

I have a folder called **tomcat**

Inside that, I have a `tar file` and `Dockerfile`

Commands to do the whole process just for understanding

```
$ pwd
/home/user/Documents/dockerfiles/tomcat/

$ ls
apache-tomcat-7.0.84.tar.gz  Dockerfile
```

**Sample Docker file:**

```
FROM ubuntu_docker
COPY apache-tomcat-7.0.84.tar.gz /home/test/
...
```

**Docker commands:**

```
$ docker build -it testserver .

$ docker run -itd --name test1  testserver

$ docker exec -it bash
```

**Now you are inside docker container**

```
# ls
apache-tomcat-7.0.84.tar.gz
```

As you can see I am able to copy `apache-tomcat-7.0.84.tar.gz` from host to Docker container.

Notice the Docker Documentation first line which you have shared

> The path must be inside the context of the build;

So as long as the path is reachable during build you can copy.

**Another way of doing this would be using volume**

```
docker run -itd -v $(pwd)/somefolder:/home/test  --name test1  testserver
```

Notice **-v** parameter

You are telling Docker to mount `Current_Directory/somefolder` to Docker's path at `/home/test`

Once the container is up and running you can simply copy any file to `$(pwd)/somefolder` and it will get copied
inside container at `/home/test`

Comment: second solution worked, i added this as an argument in the jenkins pipeline.

Comment: args '-v /path/to/.ssh:/home/userincontainer/.ssh'